# Difference between two ways to access GPU in docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, gpu

I've come across two ways to give a container access to GPUs in a `docker-compose` file:

```
    environment:      
      NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: <device>
```

```
   deploy:
       resources:
         reservations:
           devices:
             - driver: nvidia
               count: 1
               capabilities: [gpu]
```

What is the difference between these two, if any? A brief search on the internet didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this document spells it out fairly well:
https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html

**This portion:**

The NVIDIA Container Toolkit provides different options for enumerating GPUs and the capabilities that are supported for CUDA containers. This user guide demonstrates the following features of the NVIDIA Container Toolkit:

Registering the NVIDIA runtime as a custom runtime to Docker

**Using environment variables to enable the following:**

**Enumerating GPUs and controlling which GPUs are visible to the container**

Controlling which features of the driver are visible to the container using capabilities

Controlling the behavior of the runtime using constraints

The second method you are manually defining the host device you want to be made available to the container. I believe NVIDIA is trying to make your life easier by offering the first Environment variable approach. I believe either would work assuming the second path was properly setting all the required fields.